# PHP use canvas (html5) to copy and then upload the copied picture to server

Tags: php, html, canvas, upload

Is it possible for html5 canvas to be used has a very strong way to upload jpg, gif and png (converted to jpg) files to a server ? Normally we would do something like this http://hungred.com/useful-information/secure-file-upload-check-list-php/ and some other measures to prevent any code in any image file to be found, changed, executed, etc
But in this case, using canvas, the only thing we are doing is a copy of the pixels, right ? So the copied image, wouldn't have any malicious code in it...

Am i right ?

Could something like this http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/2012/10/upload-images-from-the-user-hard-driveto-an-html5-canvas-easel-js-application/ be safer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your end goal to prevent malicious code in the file?

Then using client-side Javascript isn't really a serious option, as it can be freely manipulated by the user.

If you want to be super paranoid, you *could* copy the image on server side using GD or ImageMagick. That would also remove any and all Metadata from the image, which is often a good thing - images come often with much more information than the original author would want to see in the open.

Comment: how do you think a user could "corrupt" this example http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/2012/10/upload-images-from-the-user-hard-driveto-an-html5-canvas-easel-js-application/

Comment: As far as I know, there are no known vulnerabilities in any major image libraries at the moment, so it's more of a theoretical question in either case. As said, copying the image into a new one can be a good idea for increased security, but it needs to happen on server side to be useful. On client side, a malicious user could easily disable your JavaScript, and upload a corrupt image anyway

Comment: you are right, but i can prevent a user from uploading without javascript enabled. It is better i think because if i do it by server side it would be more consuming for the server...

Comment: @user sure, but it's the only way really. It's not *that* much work for the server either.

Comment: @user I'd worry about it *if and when* that actually becomes a performance problem. It probably will never happen. No point worrying about it now.